# NullPointer Exception after checking with 'if' statement

Tags: java

I have bot connected to IRC server and its not crashing all the time the bot is crashing with Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at bot.Report.main(Report.java:47)
The 47 line is

```
if (!(str.split(" ")[1].equals("QUIT") || str.split(" ")[1].equals("PART") || str.split(" ")[1].equals("JOIN")))
```

Edit more code

```
String str = null;    
PrintWriter o;
            Socket s;
            BufferedReader i1;
            s = new Socket("", 6667);
            i1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            o = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
            o.print("PASS " + "" + "\r\n");
            o.print("USER " + "" + " 0 * :" + ""
                    + "\r\n" + "NICK " + "" + "\r\n");
            o.print("JOIN " + "#test" + "\r\n");
            o.flush();
    while (s.isConnected()) {
                str = i1.readLine();
                StringBuffer stringBuffer = null;
    if (!(str.split(" ")[1].equals("QUIT") || str.split(" ")[1].equals("PART") || str.split(" ")[1].equals("JOIN"))) {
    ......
```

Comment: str is null or there is no second element from split

Comment: Show more of your code. Where do you initialize `str` ?

Comment: Well if it's null, then why are you surprised about the null pointer exception?

Comment: `String str = null;` That will obviously give a nullPointerException , Since you are trying to split a string which is null.

Comment: `null` has no `split` method (or any method nor field) so invoking it on `null` throws NPE. Also don't call `split` on same data multiple times if your data doesn't change. Call it once, store result and use it when you need it.

Comment: Read the Javadoc for [`BufferedReader.readLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--)

Comment: the str is not empty at all?

Comment: "*the str is not empty at all?*" no `null` is not the same as empty string `""`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `if(str != null)` fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

As a good practice, you should always, check for null, before requesting for any of its, properties / methods.

if you could rewrite your if statement

if(str!=null && (!(str.split(" ")[1].equals("QUIT") || str.split(" ")[1].equals("PART") || str.split(" ")[1].equals("JOIN"))))
 ......